# Get Different GCM registrationId for Different servers

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) for triggering notification to my android app. notification are triggered from my server. for example suppose the user registers an account in app then server will be sending notifications for that I am passing GCM registration id in my registration request. till now it works perfectly. now I have one more API that is another server. and I am sending the same GCM Registration Id in that request, but I am not getting any notification from that server, so from some reading I have found that each `registration_id` is associated with a particular app and its corresponding server API key i.e. a single device has different `registration_id`s for different apps Thus, we got a *MismatchSenderId* error while trying to send push notifications using the `registration_id`. how do I resolve this ? I have googled and didn't find any proper solution.

I am generating GCM registration in this way :

```
 String token = instanceID.getToken(defaultSenderId),
                        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Comment: you should have a different token for the other server. as registration_id is specifically created for an application id.

Comment: Can you explain it please ? Provide any links if you have.

Comment: Actually gcm registration id is server dependant ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have 2 different servers, I believe you have two different sender ID. So in your code, you must have 2 token, one for each server.

Sample:

Token for server 1:

```
String token = instanceID.getToken(<sender_id_1>),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Token for server 2:

```
String token2 = instanceID.getToken(<sender_id_2>),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Comment: I'll try this. And get back to you

Answer (score 1):

There can be an issue in case when a token is updated:
in InstanceIDListenerService I see no way to identify token was updated - for sender_1 or for sender_2.
So it seems when onTokenRefresh is called we have to get new tokens for both senders.

Comment: Thats may true but is it possible to create two tokens ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct to have many tokens: if there are 2 servers, you will have 2 tokens. gRenzFries shows this case in his answer.